# switch case multiple range in C

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
switch (mark / 10) {
    case 10:
    case 9:
    case 8:
    printf("The Grade is A.\n");
    break;
    case 7:
    printf("The Grade is B.\n");
}
}
}
```

mark >= 75 gives Grade A.
May I know how to edit the case 7 so that it can detect 75 and above as Grade A.
Thank You!

Comment: Why don't you use `if` statement?

Comment: How about `if (mark >= 75) { ... } else if (mark >= ...) { ... } ...`

Comment: `switch ((mark + 5) / 10)` ?

Comment: There are what? five or six different grades plus invalid input. Write a function that returns the grade and use simple `if`s in the function. Because the body of the `if` returns immediately, there's no need to use `if`/`else` chains.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division

Comment: if you do not care abut portability use gcc switch case range extension

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to use only gcc you can use switch ranges:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html

```
switch (mark) {
    case 75 ... 100:
       printf("The Grade is A.\n");
       break;

    case 70 ... 74:
       printf("The Grade is B.\n");
       break

    /*....*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this task simply use `if` statement

```
if (mark >= 75 && mark < 100) {
    //A
} else if (mark >= 70 && mark < 75) {
    //B
} else { /* Invalid */ }
```